# Where can I find the data on the geographical distribution of the species of Drosophila within various areas of the world?

Tags: data, drosophila, biogeography

Let X denote an arbitrary geographic area where drosophilas occur in the wild. I will need the answers to the questions of the following type:

> What is the three most occurring species of the genus *Drosophila* within X?

Where can I find the data on the geographical distribution of *Drosophila* species within various areas of the Earth?

Comment: @user1136: I don't see how [TaxoDros](http://www.taxodros.uzh.ch/) can help to answer a "What are the three most occurring species of the genus Drosophila in this particular country?" question. I have not found any source that contains such information.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Source: pinterest.com
I have been unable to find data on a global scale, for now here's a map on the USA.

Comment: Pinterest.com is not a source. It is a (closed) shop for stolen goods. And a map of the US doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: First, I don't see how your highly subjective opinion lacking any basis can be following the Community Lines. Second, I advise reading the picture description in order to avoid wasting your time in such comments.

Comment: — My opinion is based on the many images stolen from websites I run and which were marked up with Pinterest’s own code to flag that they shouldn’t be copied to Pinterest. I had to request their removal, which Pinterest honoured. I was able to identify them by searching for reference to my website, and presumably you could have identified the source of the image you posted. Asking readers who may be partially sighted to read text rendered as graphics is discriminatory, but in this case clearly does not answer the question as posted.  My comment explained my down-vote.